# Why is my global command coupled with a range command matching more lines than expected?

Tags: global-command, range

I have this file over here.

```
    <ul class="social-icons">
        <li><a href=""><span class="social_linkedin_square"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="other-icons">
        <li><a href=""><span class="other-icon"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

I'm trying to only print all the list items in the file using the global command.
(i.e. lines containing `<li>...</li>` NOTE: `<li>` and `</li>` can be on separate lines)

I tried typing this in the command line:

```
:g/<li>/.,/<\/li>/p
```

But for whatever reason it's including `</ul> <ul class="other-icons">` rather than only the `<li>...</li>` lines. Alongside with a range error:

```
        <li><a href=""><span class="social_linkedin_square"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="social-icons">
        <li><a href=""><span class="another"></span></a></li>
E16: Invalid range
```

Isn't that weird since this global command matches only lines containing `<li>` and then the print command runs on each of those lines ending with `</li>` so it should stop the match at that same line? What am I missing?

UPDATE: The command works correctly **only** if `<li>` and `</li>` are on **separate** lines which is interesting.

Comment: You sure you gave us the same global command that you ran? Because the one above doesn't look right to me and, indeed, causes an Invalid Range error when I run it.

Comment: This is what I get when I run :g/<li>/.,/<\/li>/p
        ```<li><a href=""><span class="social_linkedin_square"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="social-icons">
        <li><a href=""><span class="another"></span></a></li>
E16: Invalid range```

Comment: You should include that information in your question. (Hit the "Edit" link to do so.)

Comment: @BLayer just edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the documentation I found the answer. This is not related to the global command but mainly due to cmdline-ranges operating on the **NEXT** line matching the pattern rather than same or next line which I originally thought.

```
:h cmdline-ranges
    /{pattern}[/]   the next line where {pattern} matches     *:/*
```

So running `:g/<li>/.,/<\/li>/p` is akin to running `:.,/<\/li>/p` on each line containing `<li>`. And since /*pattern*/ matches starting from the **NEXT** line the original expression was basically unable to find a closing `</li>` on the last match which causes the range error.

Comment: @guntbert edited to add more details. Let me know if it's missing anything else.

Comment: Looks good, thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

When you have `/` characters in your pattern is is better to use another separator, for instance `|` (see `:help :g`).

*I am guessing that too many separators are confusing the parsing engine*.

The following command will do what you want with the example you gave (the `<li>` elements are all on a single line)

```
:g|<li>.*</li>|p
```

Here I am using `|` as a separator and `.*` captures everything up to `</li>`.

Comment: I think the original intent was « for every line with the start of a list item, print from that line to the line with the closing list item »

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So this works assuming <li>and </li> are on the same line which is not always the case. But to be honest, I'm just mostly puzzled at why the specific command that I ran :g/<li>/.,/<\/li>/p would not work correctly.

Comment: @mkayyash I edited my answer with a *guess* :-))

Comment: Appreciate trying! I replaced <li> with liopen and </li> with liclose in the buffers. Then I ran :g/liopen/.,/liclose/p and got the same error so probably not a separator issue.

Comment: Actually if liopen and liclose are on separate lines. Everything works correctly.

Comment: @guntbert I figured out the reason why I was getting the range issue and posted it as a separate answer if you'd like to check it out